# How to make element not move down when there's room for it?

Tags: html, css

I had a hard time finding out how to express this question, and therefore also to search for any answers.

I am making a website where the user can make posts. these posts gets generated in articles. I want the user to be able to post several image sizes. So one article might be taller than another.

Rather than explaining it all, I will show it in an example I've created for this question. You can see it in the snippet.

**I recommend you to see the snippet in full screen**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
article {
  width: 46%;
  margin: 2%;
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" role="main">
  <article>
    <img src="https://assets.crowdsurge.com/datacapture/example/img/example_logo.png" alt="this is an image" />
    <section>
      <h1>I am left</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Prioris generis est docilitas, memoria; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Et quod est munus, quod opus sapientiae? Atqui reperies, inquit, in hoc quidem pertinacem; Non dolere, inquam, istud
        quam vim habeat postea videro;</p>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" alt="this is an image" />
    <section>
      <h1>I am right</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Prioris generis est docilitas, memoria; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Et quod est munus, quod opus sapientiae? Atqui reperies, inquit, in hoc quidem pertinacem; Non dolere, inquam, istud
        quam vim habeat postea videro;</p>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="#" alt="this is an image" />
    <section>
      <h1>I am bottom left</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Prioris generis est docilitas, memoria; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Et quod est munus, quod opus sapientiae? Atqui reperies, inquit, in hoc quidem pertinacem; Non dolere, inquam, istud
        quam vim habeat postea videro;</p>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="#" alt="this is an image" />
    <section>
      <h1>I am bottom right</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Prioris generis est docilitas, memoria; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Et quod est munus, quod opus sapientiae? Atqui reperies, inquit, in hoc quidem pertinacem; Non dolere, inquam, istud
        quam vim habeat postea videro;</p>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

as you can see in the example above, the right article has a taller image, so the article becomes taller, and therefore the bottom right article moves down, but the left bottom article moves down with it.

How do I get it to stick to the article above? This should be fairly simple to fix, but I haven't been able to fix it... Neither with different positions or with clear. Any help?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use 2 columns?

Comment: Since noone bothered to actually explain why this problem occurs: The normal document flow prevents this from working the way you want to. You'd think there is room, but because the second article in the same row is taller than the first, the empty space underneath the first won't ever be filled under normal circumstances. There is no CSS-only solution to this problem. In order to shift it where you want it, you need either manual positioning (using JS), or use CSS columns to achieve what you want. The latter is the easiest possibility, yet has a different order of elements than you wanted).

Comment: @TheThirdMan Thank you for explaining why this is happening! Highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try making it a scrollbar so that the max height isn't breached.

```
    section { overflow-y: auto; height:2%;}
```

You can also try hiding the content first and then show the rest of the content after user clicks on it. Can be easily done with javascript.

Also, you can resize the images to have a `max-height`. So the images wont take away spaces from the section.